# Javascript simple add class remove class

Tags: javascript

```
<div onclick="myFunction();"> Click Me</div>
<div id="nav" style="" class="hide">
    <ul>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
function myFunction (){
    if ("show"){
        document.getElementById('nav').style.display='none';
            } else if ("hide"){
                document.getElementById('nav').style.display='none';
            }
    }
```

Onclick the click me btn, i want to show & hide this "nav". using addclass remove class.

Please help me in this pure javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work better ?

```
<div id="btn"> Click Me</div>
<div id="nav" style="" class="hide">
    <ul>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    var menu = document.getElementById('nav');
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
        if (menu.className == "hide"){
            menu.className = "show";
        } else {
            menu.className ='hide';
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .show {
        display: inherit;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, This is working fine.

How do i do instant of  display - block & inline.

I want to do this by ADD class & remove class..

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want, you need to have too classes like `hide` and `display` ? Don't forget to upvote if I helped you :) @user3852173

Comment: I am having 2class for the id=nav onclick btn i want to add & remove class in nav = hide & show.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("nav").classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yxa2mnL/)

Comment: How do i implement this?

Unexpected token - error message its showing

Answer (score 0):

Store your element, just for tidier code.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('nav');
```

Using display

```
myElement.style.display = 'none'; // Hide element
myElement.style.display = 'block'; // Show block elements (div, p)
myElement.style.display = 'inline'; // Show inline elements (span, a)
```

Using Visibility:

```
myElement.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Hide element
myElement.style.visibility = 'visible'; // Show element
```

Thus using the same code to check for the styles within the if statements.

```
function myFunction ()
{
    if (myElement.style.display == "none")
        myElement.style.display='block';
    else
         myElement.style.display='none';
 }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/366aofbo/