# How to make a css animation play forward or reverse on demand

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a css animation that depending on some situation I want to be able to toggle forwards or backwards at any time based on some JS. Heres a basic example:

html

```
<div id="box"></div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
```

js

```
window.isSmall = true;
window.toggle = function() {
    if (isSmall) {
    var el = document.getElementById("box");
    el.classList.add("bigger");
  } else {
    // ????
  }
  isSmall = !isSmall;
}
```

css

```
@keyframes bigger {
    from { width:100px; height:100px; }
    to { width:200px; height:200px; }
}

#box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.bigger {
    animation-name: bigger;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gbh408up/

I thought this would be pretty straight-forward but surprisingly I wasn't able to find a method to accomplish this. Note, I'm specifically looking for a solution with animations, NOT transitions. Any ideas?

Comment: probably 2 animation ?

Comment: And why do you want to use an hammer when you need a screw-driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with 2 classes that animate what is required.

```js
window.isSmall = true;
window.toggle = () => {
  const box = document.getElementById("box");
  if (isSmall) {
    box.classList.remove("smaller");
    box.classList.add("bigger");
  } else {
    box.classList.remove("bigger");
    box.classList.add("smaller");
  }
  isSmall = !isSmall;
  console.log(isSmall)
}
```

```css
@keyframes bigger {
  from {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}

@keyframes smaller {
  from {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.bigger {
  animation-name: bigger;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.smaller {
  animation-name: smaller;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Huh, thats funny I thought I had already tried this but I must have fat fingered something along the way and missed it. This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just finished figuring this out. So here is my solution:

```
<div id="box"></div>

<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>

window.isSmall = true;
window.toggle = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("box");
    if (el.className == "a") {
    el.className = "b";
    } else {
    el.className = "a";
  }
  isSmall = !isSmall;
  console.log('toggle');
 }


@keyframes a {
    from { width:100px; height:100px; }
    to { width:200px; height:200px; }
}
@keyframes b {
    from { width:200px; height:200px; }
    to { width:100px; height:100px; }
}

#box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.a {
    animation-name: a;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.b {
  animation-name: b;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

I changed the "bigger" to just "a" and my "smaller" to just "b". But this works. Ok - I have it in a fiddle now.

https://jsfiddle.net/markem/2b6n3gmc/1/

Also, this was somewhat answered with this question here on StackOverflow:

[Javascript simple add class remove class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270285/javascript-simple-add-class-remove-class)